# Javascript - Can't access dynamic created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic, element

I am passing a dynamically created table via the following command to my jsp website:
`response.getWriter().write(responseString);`

In one column of the table is a function, which i want to call (timestamp -> create  a countdown).

That's the point where i am totally lost. I cannot call the function, cause it is a string: e.g. `"window["createCountDown()"](2,2018-07-11 01:02:03.0))"`

How can i call the function createcountdown on the several tds of the table? i am not able to access the tds of the table.. (Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null)

Comment: perhaps if you show your code, or a minimal example, your question will be clearer - as it stands, it's hard to guess what you are asking

Comment: Add that javascript inside of a `script` tag

Comment: Okay, first of all, thanks for the reply. I added the script tag. Now the <td></td> is empty. The function isn't called. (Stringname.append("<td id=" + "test" + "><script>window[\"createCountDown()\"](" + item.getTaskID() + ",'" + auctionlist.getBidTime() + "')</script></td>") -> Any further suggestions?